# How to periodically change the order of two elements in each row of a div

Tags: html, django, jinja2

In one of the HTML files of my Django project, I have a `div` that contains a `col-6` for an image and a `col-6` for a text.

```
{% if automotives %}
{% for automotive in automotives %}
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 my-5 pl-5">
                    <h3 class="font-weight-bold">{{ automotive.title }}</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">{{ automotive.description|safe }}</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 my-5 pr-5">
                    <div class=" overlay z-depth-1-half">
                        <img src="{{ automotive.cover.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="cover">
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I read `title` and `description` and `cover` from the database.

I want to periodically change the order of **image** and **text** in each row.

I have no idea how to do it. and I don't know much about js or jquery.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with flex, but I see that your question is django/jinja2 related so, this is how I would approach this problem:

Build a partial template like this

```
{% if image_right %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 my-5 pl-5">
        <h3 class="font-weight-bold">{{ automotive.title }}</h3>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ automotive.description|safe }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 my-5 pr-5">
        <div class=" overlay z-depth-1-half">
            <img src="{{ automotive.cover.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="cover">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 my-5 pr-5">
        <div class=" overlay z-depth-1-half">
            <img src="{{ automotive.cover.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="cover">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 mb-4 mb-md-0 my-5 pl-5">
        <h3 class="font-weight-bold">{{ automotive.title }}</h3>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ automotive.description|safe }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

You can name this something like `image_text.html`.
This template contains a bit of duplicate code, but it is simple to understand.

If `image_right` variable is `True` (or set to any non null value), it will show the row with the image on the right.

If `image_right` variable is `False`, (or 0 or any other null value), it will show the image left (so, image on the left is the the default behavior in this case).

Then, in your main template, you can use this partial template you just built (`image_text.html`) like this, for example, if you want to switch image on left and right on each row:

```
{% if automotives %}
    {% for automotive in automotives %}
       {% include 'image_text.html' with automotive=automotive image_right=forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

`forloop.counter` is the index of your for loop (it starts from 1, user `forloop.counter0` if you want a counter that starts from 0).

When `forloop.counter` is even, `image_right` in your partial template will be `True`, so it will show image on the right.

When `forloop.counter` is odd, `image_right` in your partial template will be `False`, so it will show image on the left.

Hope it helps. This may need some tweaks though.